# Angular routes and parameters don't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I've the following controller:

```
app.controller('ObjectBoardCtrl', ['$scope' , '$rootScope' , '$routeParams' , 
  function($scope , $rootScope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.selectedObjectId = $routeParams.id;
}]);
```

And this route config:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $routeParams) {
    $routeProvider.when('/object/:id', {
        controller: 'ObjectBoardCtrl'
      });
  }]);
```

The $routeParams object is null what ever I do. I'm trying to access different pages with #/object/4334 and have links on my page to different IDs but it refuses to update the $routeParams object.
Needless to say that the ngRoute is injected and there are no errors on the console.
What am I missing here? (I'm following pretty much every tutorial I found).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you including `ngRoute` as a dependency?

Comment: @lucuma - yep, otherwise my app doesn't even work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `$routeParams` from your config function, you don't need them over there. Use empty template, so your route looks like this:

`app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/object/:id', {
        controller: 'ObjectBoardCtrl',
        template: ''
      });
  }]);`

Use `<div ng-view></div>` in your html file as a container for the controller.

Comment: This is getting really close! I can see that the scope object is being updated with the right id but now all my html is gone :-/

Comment: ok, now you need to take any Angular related code from inside `<div ng-controller="ObjectBoardCtrl"></div>` and either place it in your route - `template: 'code goes here'` or better - in separate file `'objectBoard.tmpl.html'` and then link to it from your route like this --> `template: 'objectBoard.tmpl.html'` . That way your router takes care of assigning a controller and a template to the path in your address bar and sending the contents of the template into `ng-view`.

Comment: well, I changed it to templateUrl and took my html outside and it seems to work now, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you're right. When linking to the file it should be  `templateUrl`. Glad you have it working now.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$scope.selectedObjectId = $route.current.params.id;
```

Inject the `$route` instead

Comment: It says that params is undefined. If I set the selectedObjectId = $route and then clicking on a link then I can see $route.current.params.id with its value.